# isset($_GET(var)) is true even if var is null or undefined

Tags: php, httprequest

I am sending multiple unset variables to am `isset()` statement, but the result is true.

So I have a form and I am sending the data via a listener and meanwhile I am printing the variables to the web console

```js
  formQuote.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fromDate = formQuote.elements["fromDate"].value;
    toDate = formQuote.elements["toDate"].value;
    apptmnt = $('input[name="apptmnt"]:checked').val();
            
    console.log(fromDate);
    console.log(toDate);
    console.log(apptmnt);

    $('#priceDisplay').load('forms/quote.php?fromDate=' + fromDate + '&toDate=' + toDate + '&apptmnt=' + apptmnt);
```

As I haven't entered anything, the console shows 2 empty lines (fromDate, toDate) and undefined, upon clicking submit. The data is catched by a php file

```php
if (isset($_GET['fromDate'], $_GET['toDate'], $_GET['apptmnt'])) {
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo 'false'; 
}
```

In return I see `true`!?

My understanding based on the documentation is that isset returns true only if all arguments are true, so `isset($a, $b)` is the same as `isset($a)*isset($b)`

Any ideas what ca cause this?

Comment: You have put the parameters into the URL you are requesting, therefor they _are_ set. That the _value_ of those parameters might only be an empty string or `undefined`, does not matter. Maybe you want to go and check what the difference between `isset` and `empty` is?

Comment: Use `if (!empty($_GET['fromDate']) && !empty($_GET['toDate']) && !empty($_GET['apptmnt'])) {`, `isset` will check if the key exist in your url parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample code show difference between `isset` and `empty`

```php
<?php
$a = array('blank'=>'');
var_dump(isset($a['blank']));  // bool(true)
var_dump(!empty($a['blank'])); // bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending those parameters in the query string even if they are null or undefined. You should only send parameters when they are not empty. isset checks if variable is present and not null but in this case as you are sending it thorough JS even if they are null in JS it might sent them as empty string which is not null, so that's why isset returns true. So you should check it before calling your page.

```
if (fromDate && toDate && apptmnt) {
    $('#priceDisplay').load('forms/quote.php?fromDate=' + fromDate + '&toDate=' + toDate + '&apptmnt=' + apptmnt);
} else {
    $('#priceDisplay').load('forms/quote.php');
}
```

Comment: that is what I thought of, was just kind of lazy to account for things like all are set except fromDate, so I have to remove `&` before toDate. But I guess !empty is a more convenient way

Comment: @w461 Yes, using empty is more appropriate here but if your input can have 0 as value then empty can cause problems too cause it 0 is considered empty, so it is good idea to look how empty and isset works. You can read nice article about it from [here](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/)

Comment: very helpful comment, one variable can be 0, indeed. So back to work... Cheers!